# Выполнить запрос без join

Tags: mysql, база-данных, clickhouse

Есть таблица, со следующей структурой

```
timestamp
user_id
event
```

Есть два важных `event`

`appInstall
sessionstart`

Мне нужно посчитать количество начатых сессий в день установки приложений

Установка - это либо

```
Select
    user_id,
    toDate(min(timestamp)) as installday,
FROM
   table
GROUP BY user_id
```

либо

```
SELECT
  user_id,
  toDate(timestamp)
From
    table
where event="install"
```

В идеале тут бы подошел `join` , но так как это clickhouse тут это решение не очень хорошо впишется. Также есть идея пронумеровать все дни у игроков и сделать просто запрос

```
select
 user_id,
 count(*) 
from 
table 
where live_day=1 and event="session_start" 
group by user_id
```

Хорошее ли это решение, как лучше нумеровать дни в CH ? в Mysql для этого юзал переменные

Answer (score 0):

Значения колонки `timestamp` преобразовать в `date` и, затем, посчитать события установки:

```
SELECT
  DATE(`timestamp`),
  user_id,
  COUNT(*)
FROM `table`
WHERE `event` = 'install'
GROUP BY user_id, DATE(`timestamp`);
```

Демо на [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9tcvBrbTbyQj43wq7VJvjw/0).